# Issue executing Automation with Selenium/Nosetest set ups

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python, chromedriver, ubuntu

having issue just trying to automate for the first time.  I have access to repositories by GIT, where its python folders all use Python 2.7 syntax.  I also have Google chrome driver as well(Using ubuntu).  When I attempt to automate, I just get error, regarding python 2.7.  Unsure if thats the issue.

So a friend of mine gave me a python code, that would use google chrome driver to test if I can automate with the python code that is scripted for use once executed.  Using the command terminal, I get the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "autotimesheet.py", line 254, in <module>
    processPDCI(res)
File "autotimesheet.py", line 85, in processPDCI
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver')
File "/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
       packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
       packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver' 
executable may have wrong permissions. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

So unsure how to solve it. Friend is also stumped, and suggested to ask online.  I have use pip install selenium & pip install nose for set up.  So any guidance/help would be appreciated.  I will troubleshoot for a while to see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When your Python Selenium bindings locate the `chromedriver` executable and try to execute it, they are unable to do so because of an issue with permissions.

Most likely, your `chromedriver` executable is missing "execute" permissions, add them:

```
sudo chmod +x `which chromedriver`
# or sudo chmod +x /path/to/chromedriver
```

Comment: Okay, will update you later

Answer (score 0):

Just to update. I was able to automate the script.  Here was the only step I did:  In the autotimesheet.py, I change the line of code of this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver/)
```

to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver/chromedriver')
```

where the last part is the executable file.  So it opened up chrome and started to automate. I also did the chmod +x chromedriver command that showed that I am able to use it. Now that I know this can automate, have to fix the issue with the repositories part.

Being able to fix the automation python script issue, I have to tackle the last issue.  I will still follow the comments, and will troubleshoot.  My error for this issue is as follows:

ERROR: tests.test_to_run.TestsToRun.test_run_this_test

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
File 
"/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/tests/test_to_run.py", 
line 25, in test_run_this_test
self.test_controller.insert_steps_from_script_into_list_array()
 File 
 "/home/myName/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/lib/
web_interface/test_controller.py", line 337, in 
insert_steps_from_script_into_list_array
self.process_msg_insert(data)
 File 
"/home/myName/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/lib/web_interface/
test_controller.py", line 200, in process_msg_insert
```

So that is what i'm working on.  I will update hours later.  But thanks alecxe for comment suggestion!